# How to SSH into a local Ubuntu Server with Mac terminal?

Tags: macos, ubuntu, ssh, terminal, ubuntu-12.04

I have been a Windows user all my life and I just got a Mac recently. With Windows (puTTY), I have "SSHed" into a local Ubuntu Server dozens of times in the past. I attempted to perform the same steps with my Mac, but I am not able to make any significant progress. Can anyone provide a guide as to how to SSH into a local Ubuntu Server?

I have a clean installation of Ubuntu Server running right now. Here is a picture of when I do "ifconfig":
[image: ifconfig]

The steps that I have done previously are as follows:

1. Install openSSH Server
2. In terminal, "ssh anish@localhost"
3. Connection is timed out or my password is not accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to bridged in ur VM settings in virtual box and use ssh anish@inet